# Use same browser for multiple test cases Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I've been searching around to find if there is any setting in order to re-use the same browser for the multiple test cases. I am testing the website that requires login each time the browser is started.

Is there anything that would allow me to use the same browser session to perform one test after another without closing the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Katalon Studio will close the session after each testcase because it is a good practice of doing Web UI test. However, users has the right to manage the behavior themselves. You can uncheck the Terminate browser at "Preferences -> Katalon -> Execution".