# Groovy => Issues Saving Browser Sessions to Excel File to Reaccess later (Can't cast String back to WebDriver session)

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, groovy, webdriver, katalon-studio

**Anyone have any ideas on the below scenario?**

Background:

- Using Katalon Studio running Groovy built on Selenium framework
- I am attempting to save WebDriver sessions to an excel file so I can keep the session open and switch back to it from a different test suite later on. I was originally using global variables, but those are cleared out at the end of a test suite and cant be accessed in future test suites.

Progress:

- I have an excel file that saves off various browser sessions
- I have a custom method to retrieve those browser sessions in later test suites
- I attempt to switch to a saved session in later test suites

Current Issue:

- I believe these sessions are auto-converted from ChromeDriver sessions to Strings when saved in the excel.
- When I attempt to switch to one of those saved sessions, I need to pass in a WebDriver session instead of a String.
- When I try to use DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(savedSession), I get an error:

  `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.changeWebDriver() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (60eece5a63846ce173f7a30dfb7409b8)]Possible solutions: changeWebDriver(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver), closeWebDriver()`

Potential Solutions:

- Use something other than Excel Data File (something that can store and transfer WebDriver sessions without converting them)
- Figure out how to convert string back to WebDriver session

**Anyone have any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

changeWebDriver method expects to get WebDriver instance as argument, not sessionId, or session. So you not able to save WebDriver instance to excel and restore it.

Of course, you coluld try somehow to create a new driver session and override session Id, but it's tricky (I not found working solution for java).

Not sure, but look at this thread:

[Use same browser for multiple test cases Katalon Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889060/use-same-browser-for-multiple-test-cases-katalon-studio)